# SwiftUI - Best pattern to simplify a view init() that's the same across different views

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-protocols

Take this simple view. It has a `@StateObject` that is used within the view to automatically load and parse some data. I have many of these views with different loaders and parsers.

```
struct SomeView {
    
    @StateObject var loader: Loader<SomeParser> = Loader<SomeParser>()
    
    var body: some View {
        // Some body that uses the above loader
        VStack {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

The loaders are set to use `@MainActor` and since the `swift 5.6` update I get the new warning about initiating these with a default value and that it will be an error in `swift 6`

> Expression requiring global actor 'MainActor' cannot appear in
> default-value expression of property '_loader'; this is an error in
> Swift 6

There's a simple fix, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71396296/how-do-i-fix-expression-requiring-global-actor-mainactor-cannot-appear-in-def). We simply set it in the `init`

```
struct SomeView {
    
    @StateObject var loader: Loader<SomeParser>
    
    init() {
        self._loader = StateObject(wrappedValue: Loader<SomeParser>())
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        // Some body that uses the above loader
        VStack {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Now the issue I have, is that I have 20+ of these views, with different loaders and parsers and I have to go through each and add this `init`.

I thought, let's simply create a class that does it and subclass it. But it's a `View` `struct` so that's not possible to subclass.

Then I had a go at using a `protocol`, but I couldn't figure out a way to make it work as overriding the `init()` in the protocol doesn't let you set `self.loader = ...`

Is there a better way to do this, or is adding an `init` to every view the only way?

Comment: Strange. The fix is just as hacky: Apple says you shouldn't use that initializer: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stateobject/init(wrappedvalue:)

Comment: @atultw, that is outdated comment, on WWDC they confirmed that this is a valid way. For long time holy-war :) read comments in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62636048/12299030 (with finally got link to WWDC).

Comment: @Darren, yes as this is a view struct and property wrapper in struct you have to go through each of them and update manually. (Actually it is the same as you did when created each of them).

Comment: @Asperi wow thanks! I didn't know that... they should update the docs

Comment: @Asperi Thanks. It's boiler plate code I have to copy and paste every time I create a new view, and it just gets bigger. Not very DRY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, actually it is possible (I don't know all your 20+ views, but still) to try using generics to separate common parts and generalise them via protocols and dependent views.

Here is a simplified demo of generalisation based on your provided snapshot. Tested with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2

*Note: as you will see the result is more generic, but it seems you will need more changes to adapt it than you would just change inits*

1. Separate model into protocol with associated type and required members

```
protocol LoaderInterface: ObservableObject {  // observable
    associatedtype Parser    // associated parser
    init()                   // needed to be creatable

    var isLoading: Bool { get }   // just for demo
}
```

2. Generalize a view with dependent model and builder based on that model

```
struct LoadingView<Loader, Content>: View where Loader: LoaderInterface, Content: View {

    @StateObject private var loader: Loader
    private var content: (Loader) -> Content

    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Loader) -> Content) {
        self._loader = StateObject(wrappedValue: Loader())
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        content(loader)    // build content with loader inline
                           // so observing got worked 
    }
}
```

3. Now try to use above to create concrete view based on concrete model

```
protocol Creatable {    // just helper
    init()
}


// another generic loader (as you would probably already has)
class MyLoader<T>: LoaderInterface where T: Creatable {
    typealias Parser = T    // confirm to LoaderInterface

    var isLoading = false

    private var parser: T
    required init() {       // confirm to LoaderInterface
        parser = T()
    }
}

class MyParser: Creatable {
    required init() {}      // confirm to Creatable
    func parse() {}
}

// demo for specified `LoadingView<MyLoader<MyParser>>`
struct LoaderDemoView: View {
    var body: some View {
        LoadingView { (loader: MyLoader<MyParser>) in
            Text(loader.isLoading ? "Loading..." : "Completed")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Most of what I had was similar to this so I was able to adapt it. I had to refactor all the views, but there is now less code in each view, and no init's :)